# If a polynomial $g(x)$ is equal to zero at $a$ ( $g(a) = 0$ ) then we can write $g(x) = (x - a)^k\cdot g_1(x)$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

It's written in my book that $g(x)$ is polynomial and if it's equal to zero at $a$, that is $ g(a) = 0 $ then we can write $g(x) = (x - a)^k\cdot g_1(x)$. Well, this proposition popped in my book without any description or derivation. Can anybody give me an intuition of what it means and derive it? Furthermore, I read this in the portion "Limits of rational functions". What this expression could mean in that context?

Answer (score 7):

This follows from the Euclidean division of polynomials, which implies
$$
g(x) = (x-a)q(x)+g(a)
$$
Thus, $a$ is a root of $g$ iff $x-a$ divides $g$ and so $g(x)=(x-a)q(x)$.

Now repeat the argument with $q$. If $a$ is not a root of $q$, then we're done. If $a$ is a root of $q$, then $q(x)=(x-a)q_2(x)$ and so $g(x)=(x-a)^2q_2(x)$.

This process cannot go on forever because the degree of the quotient is decreasing. We end up with $g(x)=(x-a)^k q_k(x)$ with $q_k(a)\ne 0$.

Comment: Satisfied a "proof-on-demand non question" which is nothing more than a PSQ.  Can't and won't thank you, because this site was never meant to be a do-my-homework-for-me site, and it becoming such a site as a result of rep-desperate users doing help-vampire's homework/proofs/assignments *FOR them* and not *With them*.

Comment: @amWhy, This question and others recently closed by you seem to me perfectly good questions by a newbie. I can't and won't judge their reasons for asking them here. I understand the motivation for keeping this site "clean" but alienating newbies by equating them with help-vampires does not seem to be a good strategy.

Comment: Some newbies (in the sense of, users whose account on the site was opened recently, which is no proof that they are "newbies" in the classical meaning of the term) are help vampires, some are not. Do you suggest that below a given rep, say, vampire activities should be renamed (and treated) otherwise? What would be a rationale for this move?

Answer (score 0):

This can be proven simply using the *Euclidean division Algorithm*.

For example,

$g(x)=x^3+x^2+3x+3$, and $g(-1)=0$, so you can divide $x^3+x^2+3x+3$ with $x+1$

Using Euclidean division you will get :$\frac{x^3+x^2+3x+3}{x+1}=x^2+3$

So you can write $g(x)=(x+1)(x^2+3)$

*Note*: The $k$ you mentioned is the multiplicity of the zero/root. In this case the multiplicity is $1$ so $k=1$

Answer (score 0):

Well, let $$g(x)=g_0+g_1x+\dots+g_nx^n$$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ - so $g_n\neq0$.

Write down the euclidean division of $g(x)$ with the polynomial $(x-a)$:
$$g(x)=(x-a)p(x)+\pi(x)$$
where $\deg\pi(x)<\deg(x-a)=1$ or $\pi(x)=0$. So $\pi(x)=c$, where $c$ is a constant. Note also that 
$$g(a)=0\Leftrightarrow\pi(a)=0\Leftrightarrow c=0$$
So, we have that:
$$g(x)=(x-a)p(x)$$
So, the wanted result has been proved - with $k=1$. Now, it is obvious that, 
if $p(a)=0$, then there exists another polynomial $p_1(x)$ such that:
$$p(x)=(x-a)p_1(x)$$
So
$$g(x)=(x-a)^2p_1(x)$$
where $\deg g(x)=n>\deg p(x)=n-1>\deg p_1(x)=n-2$, we can continue this way until we find a polynomial $p_k(x)$ that is not divisible by $(x-a)$, where $\deg p_k(x)=n-k-1$ and $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$. Then we have that:
$$g(x)=(x-a)^{k+1}p_k(x)$$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to basics:

Define $f(x)=g(x+a)$. Then it's also true that $g(x)=f(x-a)$.

$f$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $g$ and $f(0)=g(0+a)=0$. That means its constant coefficient is $0$:

$$f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x$$

Then we define

$$f_1(x)=a_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2x+a_1$$

and we can see that $f(x)=xf_1(x)$. What follows is:

$$g(x)=f(x-a)=(x-a)f_1(x-a)$$

Calling $g_1(x)=f_1(x-a)$, we see that $g(x)=(x-a)g_1(x)$. Note that $g_1$ is one degree less than $g$.

If $g_1(a)$ is still $0$, we know already that $g_1(x)=(x-a)$ times another polynomial, let's call it $g_2(x)$, so $g(x)=(x-a)^2g_2(x)$. Repeating until we end up with non-zero $g_k$, we get

$$g(x)=(x-a)^kg_k(x)$$

**Example**: $g(x)=x^3-8$, $g(2)=0$.

Then we have

$$f(x)=g(x+2)=(x+2)^3-8=x^3+3\cdot2x^2+\cdot4x+8-8=x^3+6x^2+12x$$
$$f_1(x)=x^2+6x+12$$

You already knew the constant coefficient of $f$ would be zero because $f(0)=g(0+2)=0$. Then $f(x)=xf_1(x)$. Next we do

$$g_1(x)=f_1(x-2)=(x-2)^2+6(x-2)+12=\cdots=x^2+2x+4$$

The way we arrived at $g_1$, it should be no surprise (but try if you wish) that

$$g(x)=(x-2)g_1(x)=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$$

Because $g_1(2)\neq0$, we came to an end. In this example $k=1$.